# Trying to scroll over cover image but loosing image quality

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a page scroll over a cover image,

but my image is getting really distorted and low quality,

have i done my code right?

is there anyway of doing this without sacrificing quality of image?

http://www.real-creative.co.uk/new/test.php

Comment: Use a higher res image?

Comment: Is image loosing quality due to scrolling or is it also low quality before apply the scrolling routines?

Comment: It's losing quality because the source of your image (http://www.real-creative.co.uk/new/images/work/mainBanner_houseVapour.png) is 1600x688, but you use it in a background context that centers it, filling the image to the viewport. That effectively zooms in, and so makes the compression artifacts more apparent. Use a higher res image, dispense with the image in favor of a pattern, or use a vector image type such as SVG.